why my skeleton pose is in one point
Why is my skeleton pose in animation at one point? Edit Mode is no problem, but the skeleton pose is at the one point in pose mode. How can I fix it? Like this 

another animation is no problem too


hello could you please share your file?

Oh thank you， but I don't know how I can share you， can you give me your email？  Or I can give you an email from me

read the instructions https://blend-exchange.com/ or use another platform like workupload and share the link

I uploaded it but the files have other plug-ins. I am not sure they can work...

https://github.com/SakuraiAkino/NONe   i m uploaded in GitHub

someone can help me？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？？

Your bones have custom shapes, if you want to come back to basic shapes, go into Pose mode, select all the bones, reset the pose with AltG, go into the Bone panel, press Alt then click on the X to close the custom shape:

Then go into the Data panel and select the octahedral shape instead of the stick:

If you want to make them look bigger, select them all in Edit mode, select Transform Pivot Point > Individual Origins and scale up:

